# Encountered metric with name "scrollview", but value was not specified in metrics or views dictionaries

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to implement some code found here, but it give me this error. I suppose it must have some syntax error, but I can't read it out from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3-SW1).

Here is the code:

```
[scrollView addSubview:containerView];

[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[containerView(620)]|"
                            options:0 metrics:nil
                            views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(containerView)]];

[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[containerView(==scrollView)]|"
                            options:0 metrics:nil 
                            views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(containerView)]]; //error here
```

Answer (score 2):

The metric *scrollView* is not found by the NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat method because you are **only** binding the *containerView* for the *views* dictionary parameter.

Try the following instead:

```
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[containerView(==scrollView)]|"
                            options:0 metrics:nil 
                            views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(containerView, scrollView)]];
```